# Out of bound answers from sql server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select 
  e.E_ID as Employee_ID,
  e.E_NAME as Employee_Name, 
  convert(varchar(10),a.Date,103) as Date ,
  convert(varchar(8),a.Timein,108) as Time_In, 
  convert(varchar(8),a.Timeout,108) as Time_Out 
from Employee e 
LEFT JOIN Attendance a  
  ON a.E_ID = e.E_ID 
  AND (convert(varchar(10),a.Date,103) between '01/02/2013' And '28/02/2013')
```

Above is my query, I am fetching the data from two tables but it is printing values of january as well which is not in query.

I've been debugging for an hour, Kindly please any one help.

Comment: @AlfredSanz and not even furious ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BETWEEN` and `dd/mm/yyyy` formatted strings isn't going to work!

To bring back rows in February use

```
   LEFT JOIN Attendance a
     ON a.E_ID = e.E_ID  AND a.Date BETWEEN '20130201' AND '20130228'
```

Or if the values in `a.Date` might have a time component other than `00:00:00`

```
   LEFT JOIN Attendance a
     ON a.E_ID = e.E_ID  AND a.Date >= '20130201' AND a.Date < '20130301'
```

Casting the column to `varchar` is unsargable and means an index seek can't be used,

Comment: The conversion of char data type to smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range smalldatetime value. (This is what i got if i dont typecast it)

Comment: @WajahatKareem - That isn't coming from the code in my answer. All the values cast to `smalldatetime` fine. `SELECT CAST('20130201' AS SMALLDATETIME), CAST('20130228' AS SMALLDATETIME), CAST('20130201' AS SMALLDATETIME), CAST('20130301' AS SMALLDATETIME)`

Answer (score 1):

```
Try below and see if it helps

select 
  e.E_ID as Employee_ID,
  e.E_NAME as Employee_Name, 
  convert(varchar(10),a.Date,103) as Date ,
  convert(varchar(8),a.Timein,108) as Time_In, 
  convert(varchar(8),a.Timeout,108) as Time_Out 
  from Employee e 
  LEFT JOIN Attendance a  
  ON a.E_ID = e.E_ID 
  Where (convert(varchar(10),a.Date,103) between '01/02/2013' And '28/02/2013')
```

Comment: This converts the left join back to an inner join.

Comment: what is the difference from my query?

Comment: @WajahatKareem - The only difference is that they have moved the predicate into the `WHERE` rather than the `OUTER JOIN` condition. It won't resolve your issue and changes the semantics of the query. Your issue is that `dd/mm/yyyy` as a string is bever going to work as you want when using `BETWEEN`

Comment: Thanx for the help. But the above is not working as MartinSmith wrote.

Comment: @WajahatKareem I agree with MartinSmith . I overlooked your And condition

Comment: @MartinSmith Agree with you